# Automtically change page style at first chapter

Tags: koma-script, page-numbering, documentclass-writing

I'm looking for a way to change the page style with the *first* occurrence of a `chapter` using KOMA-Class `scrreprt`. It would be ideal if the change happens automatically without user interaction so I can hide the logic inside my custom class `myownclass`.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
% \documentclass{myonwclass}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\author{Max Mustermann}
\title{SE Question}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    % No page numbering wanted here
    \pagenumbering{Roman} % Just for demo

    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    % Change page style automically
    % No need to print \pagenumbering or whatever
    \chapter{The first chapter has appeared}
    \pagenumbering{arabic} % Start counting page number and show them

    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

It would be nice if there is a possiblity **without** introducing a new command like `\frontmatter` or `\mainmatter`.

Comment: You do realise that the lists are chapters too, right?

Comment: No I didn't. So I may need some other solution?

Comment: I think you already found a simple solution. Mainmatter and front matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumed switching to Arabic page numbers should be done at the first numbered chapter you could patch `\chapterlinesformat` and `\chapterlineswithprefixformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\chapterlinesformat}{%
  \autoswitchtoarabicpagenumbering{#1}{#2}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\xpretocmd{\chapterlineswithprefixformat}{%
  \autoswitchtoarabicpagenumbering{#1}{#2}%
}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\autoswitchtoarabicpagenumbering}[2]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}{%
    \IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{}{\pagenumbering{arabic}}%
  }%
  \global\let\autoswitchtoarabicpagenumbering\@gobbletwo
}
\makeatother
\pagenumbering{Roman}

\author{Max Mustermann}
\title{SE Question}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    % Change page style automically
    % No need to print \pagenumbering or whatever
    \chapter{The first chapter has appeared}

    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

However, I would suggest not to do so, but use `scrbook` instead of `scrreprt` and do the switching using `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter`:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd{\frontmatter}{roman}{Roman}{}{\PatchFailed}% use uppercase Roman
                                % page numbers instead of lowercase

\author{Max Mustermann}
\title{SE Question}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{The first chapter has appeared}

    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

This solution gives you more control how and where to do the wanted changes of the different document segments.

Comment: In this particular case switching to `scrbook` is no option. But I agree that using this class would give more control. Thanks for your answer.